# Magento2 DI compilation takes too much time

Tags: magento2, compilation

After creating/updating new module/theme, I use following command in root Magento installation directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Which asks me to run compilation, so I use

```
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

which takes around 8 minutes of time to compile it. Is there a way to fasten the compilation process?

Comment: I have reported it on GitHub 3 weeks ago: [#2893](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2893).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, compilation need only in production mode. If you develop, you do not need to run compilation

It's hard to improve compilation, because in this process build tree of all classes in system. For example change in 'di.xml' can affect half of classes.

In developer mode, if you modify/create constructor you still need to delete generated/code/ folder to remove auto generated code and cleanup cache

Comment: So, I should ignore this message in developer mode?

Comment: Yes,  You should ignor

Comment: Also, as soon you ran compilation once, there will be *.ser files in /var/di and you should delete them, otherwise they are still used.

Comment: even in developer mode, if create constructor or modify any of them, you still need to run setup:di:compile. maybe this is now required in latest magento version.

Comment: The answer looks incorrect to me. If you inject a new dependency or remove even you are in the developer mode you need to run setup:di:compile.

Comment: DoniWibowo @Suman-PHP4U I updated the response about the code changes

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You still need to run `setup:di:compile` here and then if you change a constructor.

Comment: @Black Can you provide steps to reproduce here, or on githab?