# Magento compilation hangs!

Tags: magento2, compiler

running `bin/magento setup:di:compile` hangs at 14% forever. Already allocated 1G RAM and incrased execution time 18000

running again with

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

after 20 minutes

```
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 61.2 
MiProxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 mins 70.2 M
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 mins 70.2 MiB
```

Comment: not sure if that leads somewhere, but could you try to execute it with bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv ? This should trigger the debug output. Maybe you can find something in there

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled? If you, could you try to disable it?

Comment: no I do not have xdebug

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I'm experiencing the same issue.  Stuck at 14% on `Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>------------------] 14% 7 secs 44.0 Mib`.  I've tried allocating some more ram to my VM and trying my old Ubuntu 14.04 vm and the new Ubuntu 16.04, both with PHP7 (no xdebug).

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm getting the same issue:
`Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 16 secs 87.5 MiB`

Comment: I think this may be a memory issue `Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 4 secs 42.0 MiB` not enough

Comment: Here is a good answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97541/magento2-di-compilation-takes-too-much-time

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this exact error. I disabled all my 3rd party modules one by one and surprisingly the compile was still hanging up in the same spot.

The solution to get compiling to work for me was to delete all the module files using the command  `rm -rf app/code/*` from the Magento directory.

I'm not sure why disabled modules affect compilation, but this will be useful for others to know. Also, this should go without saying, make sure you back up your `app/code/` directory before hand or you can try deleting/moving one module at a time to find out which was causing the issue.

Comment: I have just installed a new module and when decided to disable it and compile, I received this error. Deleting it from app/code/ helped resolve the issue and compilation no more hangs at 1/7 step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Look for recursive symlinks:

```
find -L . -type l -ls
```

I got the following output:

```
find: File system loop detected; ‘vendor/bim/module-bim-lib-core-magento2/Acl/Acl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘vendor/bim/module-bim-lib-core-magento2/Acl’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘vendor/bim/module-bim-lib-core-magento2/Acl/Core/Acl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘vendor/bim/module-bim-lib-core-magento2/Acl’.
```

Answer (score -2):

From command prompt type

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile [enter]
```

you will see the error.

In my case I found the error

> "cannot declare interface Magento\Backend\App\ConfigInterface, because
>   the name is already in use in
>   vendor\magento\module-checkout\Helper\Magento\Backend\App\ConfigInterface"

then I change the namespace `"Magento\Backend\App"` to `"Magento\Checkout\Helper\Magento\Backend\App"` in `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Helper\Magento\Backend\App\ConfigInterface.php`